Unable to start PC Guidewire Studio on Mac due to IDEA_HOME
I am facing some issues while starting up the studio using gwb command. I am running Policy Center version 10.2.3 and it requires an external version of IntelliJ Idea. I downloaded the Idea zip and added its location to PATH in windows. I created IDEA_HOME variable that works in Windows but the same does not get recognized on Mac. Has anyone run the latest premise version on Mac? How do you setup the path and make gwb recognize it? I get the below error on Mac even after setting the variable.
** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** You are running a version of Studio that does not have a bundled IntelliJ. ** IDEA_HOME must be set to contain the path to an installation of IntelliJ 2022.3 **  ** Studio cannot be started until this is fixed. ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **
My IDEA_HOME is set as IDEA_HOME=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app. Any idea why this does not work?

The issue is that Guidewire is looking for the path to the root directory of the IntelliJ install that contains folders like bin, lib, plugins, etc. Setting IDEA_HOME on Windows works since it is the actual directory on disk containing the IntelliJ root. However, on Mac the only way to install IntelliJ is using the dmg file (either Intel or Apple silicon).
Installing from the Dmg file, adds IntelliJ as an application. In order to expand an application's contents you can go to Applications -> right click -> Show Package Contents. Doing this to IntelliJ reveals that the actual IDEA_HOME should be set to /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents. The Contents sub-folder is missing in your case hence the error. Since the path has spaces, I also had to add double quotes and use the below line in my .zshenv file.
export IDEA_HOME=/Applications/"IntelliJ IDEA CE.app"/Contents
After this you may have to refresh the zshenv file using source ~/.zshenv and the ./gwb studio command should work fine.
You may have to follow different steps in case you are using another shell, but the IDEA_HOME environment variable would stay the same.

This worked, thank you! I was missing Contents from the path
